# Trigger button click on uploadify flash object

Tags: javascript, flash, uploadify

I want to be able to trigger a click on the "Upload" button in Uploadify - the reason being I'd like to be able to choose to upload a file from a dropdown menu and hence need to call "Upload" somehow using javascript - unless anyone has another clever idea?

The following DOES NOT work:

```
$('#file_uploadUploader').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi take alook at this link you can call some javascript function using ExternalInterface a static class and the opposit is true :

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately this requires that the ActionScript (Flash) developer write code permitting the handling of an incoming API request (from what I understand?)

Comment: humm I don't thing this is possible using only javascript for security reason

Comment: Thanks - will mark this response as the answer given that after a fair amount of research it appears that indeed this is not possible.